# Bring Python gui window to front?

Tags: python, tkinter, easygui

I'm trying to use one of Python's gui modules to retrieve a user's Twitter username and password:

Here is my first attempt (using easygui):

```
import easygui
username = easygui.enterbox("Enter your Twitter username")
password = easygui.passwordbox("Enter your Twitter password")
```

Here is my second attempt (using tkinter):

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import simpledialog

application_window = tk.Tk()
application_window.attributes("-topmost", True)
username = simpledialog.askstring("Input", "What is your Twitter username?")
password = simpledialog.askstring("Input", "What is your Twitter password?", show="*")
application_window.destroy()
```

Currently, the neither gui appears automatically. Rather, a Python icon appears on my Windows taskbar and I have to click the icon to make the gui appear. Is there any programmatic way to make the gui automatically pop up? Or perhaps there's another module I can use to achieve this?

Comment: the code you posted doesn't produce same `error` .

Comment: are you using a Windows machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simpledialog module makes a new Toplevel window, which is the one you want to bring forward, not the root window.

`simpledialog` works best when you already have a tkinter GUI running. I think you would be a lot better off with `easygui`, since it actually uses a tkinter Tk instance:

```
import easygui

fieldNames = ["Username", "Password"]
values = easygui.multpasswordbox("Enter Twitter information", "Input", fieldNames)
if values:
    username, password = values
else:
    # user pushed "Cancel", the esc key, or Xed out the window
    username, password = None, None
print(username, password)
```

If that does not work, easygui has the hook to use the topmost trick:

```
import easygui

fieldNames = ["Username", "Password"]
mb = easygui.multpasswordbox("Enter Twitter information", "Input", fieldNames, run=False)
mb.ui.boxRoot.attributes("-topmost", True)
mb.run()
if mb.values:
    username, password = mb.values
else:
    # user pushed "Cancel", the esc key, or Xed out the window
    username, password = None, None
print(username, password)
```

or just make your own dialog.

Comment: thank you for this. unfortunately, I'm having the same problem with easygui. instead of popping up automatically, a Python logo appears on the task bar and I have to click on it to open the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it quite easily using [PySimpleGUI](http://www.PySimpleGUI.org).  There are a couple of ways. One is the builtin function PopupGetText.  This will create 2 windows, one for username, one for password. Or, you can create your own custom layout that asks for both in a single window.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

username = sg.PopupGetText('Enter your username')
password = sg.PopupGetText('Entery your password', password_char='*')

layout = [[sg.Text('Username'), sg.Input()],
          [sg.Text('Password'), sg.Input(password_char='*')],
          [sg.OK()]]

button, (username, password) = sg.Window('Login').Layout(layout).Read()
```

[image: Using 2 input windows]

[image: Using 2 input windows]

[image: Using a custom GUI]